# Mac is not recognising key strokes in pygame;

Tags: python, macos, pygame

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        print('closing the window')
        running = False

    # key down for checking if a key is pressed.

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print('some key is pressed')
        if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
            print("up key is pressed")
        elif event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("Right key is pressed")
        elif event.type == pygame.K_w:
            print('w is pressed')
        else:
            print("does'nt recognize")

    # key up for checking if a key is released.
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        print('some key is released')
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print('Keystroke is released')
```

I ran the code but this is the output:
some key is pressed
does'nt recognize
some key is released
some key is pressed
does'nt recognize
some key is released
closing the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT`, however, you already know that `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` which is not equal to `pygame.K_RIGHT`. Instead, check `event.key`. This represents what key exactly is being pressed, while type just tells you that this is a keyboard event.